# How to enable @Secured annotation in spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using sprig security 4.0.4.RELEASE in my Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE application.
I want to implement the role wise security on method level in my application using `@Secured` annotation 
I'm tried to implement this by adding `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` but some error is occurring.

Here is my SecurityConfiguration Class

```html
package com.application.security;

import com.application.security.LoginSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
 UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

 @Autowired
    LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;
 
 @Autowired
 PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;
 
  
 /*@Autowired
 public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
 }*/
 
 @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
 
 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  auth.authenticationProvider(customDaoAuthenticationProvider());
 }

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/logout");
  http.authorizeRequests()
    /*.antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")*/
    .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/exclusion").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/landing").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/uploadSingle").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/uploadSingleNoFile").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/loadHtmlTableAjax").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/AllclaimDetails").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/deleteclaim").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/claimComplete").permitAll() 
    .antMatchers("/exclusionComplete").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
   .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()   
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
    .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
    .and()
         .logout()
             .logoutUrl("/logout")
             .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
             .permitAll()
             .and()
   .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository).tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
       .and()
       .csrf()
       .and()
       .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
 }
 
 @Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/logoff");
 }
  
 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }

 @Bean
 public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
  DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
  authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  return authenticationProvider;
 }
 
    @Bean
    CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider customDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
     CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider = new CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider();
     customAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
     customAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  return customAuthenticationProvider;
    }
    
 @Bean
 public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
  PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
    "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
  return tokenBasedservice;
 }

 @Bean
 public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
  return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
 }

}
```

When I'm giving `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` , the application is not getting started. I'm getting the below error.

The problem is from AuthenticationTrustResolver bean

```html
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:546 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.setAuthenticationTrustResolver(org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setTrustResolver(org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getAuthenticationTrustResolver': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Can somebody tell me the reason?

Comment: Don't add random strings of text to the end of your post to bypass SE quality measures.

Answer (score 0):

Please create `Initializer` class by extending `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`.

Please refer my answer in here.

[No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726743/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-available/50759022#50759022)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating my spring security dependency to latest in pom.xml

I changed the version from

`<springsecurity.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>`

to

`<springsecurity.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>`